# New user data not reflected in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

In our Android application we use Google Analytics API for tracking the user behaviours. Few users (5 to 10 users) are not reflected in Google analytics report but they are installed our application in their mobiles. We are using google analytics API version 4 in  our application. i would like to know reason for this not reflection of this data.

Thanks..

Comment: are the users using the latest version of Google play service?

Comment: try logcat. see if any hit has been sent to google analytics

Comment: Thanks hadi. i will try logcat to track the hit meanwhile i would like know whether users also need latest version of google play services.